# React && Rails (Ajax), right way to load css and js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I'm only learning ReactJS, so the basic rails way that I include `stylesheets_tag` to `layouts/applications.html`, and when when I do AJAX GET request and append all data in the end of the body, the first call is ok, but all others (without refreshing page) css and js files are duplicated, and I receive double shadow (in css files) and double scripts event (for example `alert` messages).

Basically, I would solve this is issue by doing `layout false` in controller, BUT, since in my view I have `react_component 'Something'`, React will not load my `Something` component.

So, my question is, what is the right way to include js and css files in Rails/React && Ajax requests? And how double call problem can be avoid?